# Possible to change the RedirectStandardInput value when the process is running?

Tags: powershell

I have written a simple PowerShell script, which opens up a CMD window and write some command(for example "ipconfig") into it through stdin. You can see the script below.

```
$p = New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo;
$p.FileName = "cmd.exe";
$p.RedirectStandardInput = $true;
$p.UseShellExecute = $false;
$pi = [System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start($p);
$pi.StandardInput.Write("ipconfig`n");
$pi.WaitForExit();
```

What I want is that to be able to enter some commands by keyboard directly to the CMD window when the script execution finishes or script reaches to "$pi.WaitForExit();" line.
Could anybody help me, please?

Comment: Or is there any other way to provide a solution for me?

Comment: I mean running a process which has input both from keyboard and stdin?